# How to convert decimal floating point to binary in Zuse style

Tags: floating-point

I want to build a replica of the Z3, and I need to get educated on the binary to decimal and decimal to binary conversion algorithms.

The algorithm used in the Z3 is supposedly this. Let's take an example number, such as 5 * 10 ^ 4. So first we convert the 5 to binary, so we have 0101 and we set it at the bit -13 of the mantissa unit. Then we add 13 to the exponent to compensate for the position t which we inputed it. Then we normalize the mantissa. So now in the exponent we have 1101 and in the mantissa 1.01. Then it says that we need to multiply the mantissa with 10 as many times as dictated by the exponent. So this would be 1.01 * 10 four times?

But this makes no sense to me. We normalized it, and now multiply? And also the algorithm never says how the exponent is actually set?

Comment: It seems to me there is a problem in the interpretation of the language describing the algorithm. You should have to show us the document you are referring to.

Comment: @EricPostpischil https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/be8b/813ffdd21a6d75172344f98ce4dcd67b2d44.pdf?_ga=2.2899248.1401448970.1549289926-823619508.1548517142

Comment: @EricPostpischil What do you mean by the input decimal exponent?

Comment: I think the description of interpreting decimal input in the “Read and Display Instructions” section that begins on page 13 omits some steps. I do not see where it discusses initialization of the floating-point registers for this operation. I suspect the exponent Ab and significand Bb are set to represent a value of zero (so Ab is set to −64), and the exponent Aa is set to represent a scale of 2^0 (so Aa is set to 0). Then a decimal digit from the input is written into Ba, and an add is performed. Then a multiply by 10 is performed, then the next input digit is written into Ba, and so on.

Comment: The normalization is built into the add and the multiply. Once four digits are processed, the significand is complete, and (Ab, Bb) contains a floating-point number that represents the significand. Then the decimal exponent *e* is processed by multiplying by 10 *e* times if *e* is non-negative or .1 | *e* | times if *e* is negative. (The exponent *e* was set by pressing input buttons on the machine.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil But you are multiplying what by e times 10?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Then the decimal exponent e is processed by multiplying by 10 e times if e is non-negative or .1 | e | times if e is negative. (The exponent e was set by pressing input buttons on the machine.)". What exactly is being multiplied by 10? Also the registers are set to 0 since they are part of the ALU Datapath.

Comment: Once the significand has been processed, the pair (Ab, Bb) contains its value. E.g., if the user pressed buttons for 0234, the pair (Ab, Bb) contains 7 in Ab and 1.1110101 in Bb, which is 1.1110101•2^7 = 234. Then, if the user pushed the button for exponent 3, the number in (Ab, Bb) is multiplied by ten 3 times.

Comment: The lowercase letter represents the register. So, when people represent addition, they do things like A + B. Since this CPU is dual core, it has the exponent and mantissa. The mantissa is referred to as part B while the exponent is part A. So Ab means register B of the mantissa unit. Same for the other section and registers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil could you please walk me through the steps of converting the example number I said, 5 * 10 ^ 4 to binary so it is more easy to understand?

Comment: Figure 3 on page 8 of the paper you linked to shows Aa and Ab as things in an exponent unit. It shows Ba and Bb as things in a significand unit. And it indicates with arrows that Ab and Bb together represent floating-point registers R2.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of time now. Maybe more later.

Comment: So wait, to multiply the 1.1110101 times 10 3 times, you get 011101111010.0001000 in the mantissa and 011001011001000 in the exponent? This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to “The Processor” starting on page 8 of [*Konrad Zuse’s Legacy: The Architecture of the Z1 and Z3*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/be8b/813ffdd21a6d75172344f98ce4dcd67b2d44.pdf?_ga=2.2899248.1401448970.1549289926-823619508.1548517142), by Raúl Rojas, the Z3 floating-point unit contains registers Aa, Ab, Ae, and Af in an sub-unit that handles exponents and registers Ba, Bb, Be, and Bf in a sub-unit that handles significands.

Together, the pair of registers <Af, Bf>  constitute a floating-point registers R1, and <Ab, Bb> constitute a register R2.

The exponent registers contain 7-8 bits, and the significand registers contain 17-19 bits. The varying numbers of bits allow for intermediate results during arithmetic.

(Note an error in the text: It says “The second shifter can displace the significand in Af from one to 16 positions to the right and from one to 15 positions to the left.” However, since Af has only 7 bits, another register must be intended. As a prior sentence indicates there is a shifter with input Bf and output Ba and another with input Bf and output Bb, I expect the Bf-to-Bb shifter is intended.)

“Read and Display Instructions” starting on page 13 tells us how decimal input is converted to binary floating-point. It appears to be missing some steps, but my interpretation is:

1. The user sets a four-digit decimal significand on the Z keyboard and an exponent from −8 to +8 on the K keyboard or buttons.
2. The floating-point unit is initialized in some way I do not see described by Rojas. Possibly RF, <Ab, Bb>, is initialized to represent the value zero (exponent −64, any significand). I will proceed on this assumption.
3. <Aa, Bb> is set to represent the value of one digit of the significand. The bits of the digit are copied into bits −10 to −13 of Ba. (The bits of Ba appear to be numbered from 0 to −18.)
4. According to Rojas, Ba is multiplied by 10. I think this is done via “microcode” that controls various relays inside the floating-point unit but have not studied the paper fully.
5. Rojas tells us steps 3 and 4 are repeated for the remaining three decimal digits, but this must be an incomplete description, because bits −10 to −13 of Ba still contain data from the multiplication by ten, so the new digit cannot be simply stored in these bits; either it must be added to Ba, or the product must have been produced elsewhere, and it will be added to the new digit. A more detailed reading of the paper might illuminate this by revealing what circuits are available to perform this addition.
6. When the above is complete, we have the decimal significand encoded in binary in Ba. I suspect this includes the explicit leading bit in bit 0, which is 0 for numbers less than 8,192 and 1 for 8,192 and greater. In the former case, the number is not normalized.
7. The exponent in Aa must also have been initialized. I suspect it is set to 13, so that <Aa, Ba> now correctly represents the decimal significant as an integer.
8. Processing of the decimal exponent uses the entire floating-point unit. At some point after preparing the decimal significand in <Aa, Ba>, it is moved to <Ae, Be>. For a non-negative exponent *e*, the number is multiplied by ten *e* times.
9. At this point, Rojas writes that the significand is shifted from Be to Ba and from Be to Bb. However, the shifters he described previously have Bf as a source, not Be, so either some step has been omitted, or the number is in <Af, Bf> rather than <Ae, Be>, or there are additional shifters I have missed.
10. Presuming the number is in <Af, Bf>, the shifters are used to copy Bf to Ba while shifting left 1 bit (which multiplies by two) and to copy Bf to Ba while shifting left 3 bits (which multiplies by eight). Then these two significands are added using the ALU labeled B in Figure 3. Additional operations not described must handle normalization, including exponent adjustment.

Rojas mentions that negative exponents are handled by multiplying by .1 but omits details of that multiplication.

Comment: So for example, for 5 * 10 ^ 4? Okay you convert the 0005 to decimal by multiplying times 10 and adding, right? So now we have 0101 at position -13. We then normalize it into 1.01 and add 13 to the exponent. Then, what would you do with the 4?

Comment: @YinXuanYang: Items 9 and 10 in the answer describe the handling of the exponent. The number is moved into Af:Bf, shifters move 2 times the number into Aa:Ba and 8 times the number into Ab:Bb. Then these are added, producing a result in Ae:Be. This result is then moved into Af:Bf, and the process is repeated *e* times.

Comment: But the exponent is "A", how would I get the exponent in the first place?

Comment: The 4 would be placed in side A, but it has to be modified due to the conversion from decimal to binary, although I don't know what must be done

Comment: The registers are not initialized in anyway and in fact, they are cleared after every single instruction so what is missing here?